# Liquibase diffChangelog does not generate rollback

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql, liquibase-pro

If I haven't misunderstood anything, the liquibase command `diffChangelog` should be able to generate rollback change sets for some types of change sets like `create table`, `rename column` or `add column` but it is not working for me using the liquibase gradle plugin version 2.0.2. Running a command like this:

```
./gradlew diffChangelog -PrunList='diffLocal' -PchangeLogFile='changelog1.mysql.sql'
```

generate create tables change sets fine but it does not add the rollback part. Did I misunderstood that Liquibase is able to do that for me?

I am using liquibase-core version 3.8.9 and liquibase-groovy-dsl version 2.1.1. I have tried many change log file formats like `xml`,`yaml`,`groovy` and `json` but none of them adds the rollback. Even with a License Key PRO rollbacks are not added.

Any idea?